# Transparent ImageView does not react for click

Tags: android, google-maps, imageview, scrollview

I'd like to use a `Google Map` inside a `SrcollView`. To that I need to use something like that:

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:id="@+id/scrollView">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/relativeinfo1">

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="35dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"/>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/titleinfo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/mooobil"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="phone"
    android:id="@+id/telefoneeo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="email"
    android:id="@+id/emailese"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:autoLink="web"
    android:id="@+id/honlapese"/>


<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageinfo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageinfo"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cimtext"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Cím: "
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:background="#FFD700" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/vonal2"
    android:background="#FFD700"/>



<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/relativemaplayout">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/transparent_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

```
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_service_info,parent, false);
    mScrollView = (ScrollView) v.findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    transparentImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.transparent_image);
    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
transparentImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            Log.d("action","down");
            switch (action) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Disallow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.d("action","down");
                    return false;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Allow ScrollView to intercept touch events.
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
                    Log.d("action","up");
                    return true;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    mScrollView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                    Log.d("action","move");
                    return false;

                default:
                    return true;
            }
        }
    });

    transparentImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "anyád", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

I don't know why but the transparent `ImageView` does not respond for click. What should I do to make the `ImageView` react for the click? I have tried some other way to make the `ScrollView` work but non of them worked and this solution looks pretty good.

Comment: plz try first,update trasparant image to any of image and check its working or not?

Comment: Yes, replace with other image, check if it is working or not and also try removing `android:onClick="onClick"` and check

Comment: @dipali If I update transparent image to a drawable image then it works fine. If I set to background or src to any type of color it doesn't work. Have you any idea?

Comment: @J.Doe just fix size of imageview temporary and put color in background ,and check its working or not?